# MVC - user name and password from my database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a new to MVC and I need some assistance attaching my account details from my SQL database to the account controller.

When you create a MVC project you have the account setting all set up. 
I have attached a database and would like to use my database to add/remove users.

How do I go about modifying the current account code to use my database users?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you create your MVC project from a template? This is always a good place to start I found. It gives you a nice road map to understand how MVC works. I have started from here on a number of projects and just built out from here.

Open a blank web project in VS and then go to the Package Manager then copy this line in the window: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples/2.0.0-beta2

There are other templates like this. But this is a good place to start. It primarily deals with Authentication because of the Identity piece but it has th4e basic MVC bit in there that is quite simple.

One way is that you can add field to the userViewModel. This also need to be done for the applicationUser class and then these will bubble through to the tables.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want but it seems that you are using template with authentication selected. If that is the case you will have asp.net identity authentication and authorization as built in feature in your template. If you don't want to use that in-built authentication you can select none for authentication while creating project and then you can implement you custom authentication in project. For custom authentication you can follow below links

http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/custom-authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-mvc
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1111522/Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-MVC